# Increasing pie chart size with matplotlib, radius parameter appears to do nothing

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pie-chart

Trying to make the pie larger. Looking at the docs, and other places, it says to set the radius. It seems no matter which value I put in the radius there's no increase. I'm posting the full code and the image it generates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def autopct_generator(limit):
    """Remove percent on small slices."""
    def inner_autopct(pct):
        return ('%.2f%%' % pct) if pct > limit else ''
    return inner_autopct

labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs', 'Test', 'Test2', 'Test3', \
    'Test4', 'Test5', 'Test6', 'Test7', 'Test8', 'Test9', 'Test10', \
    'Test11', 'Test12', 'Test13', 'Test14'
sizes = [15, 30, 45, 10, 10, 24, 13, 18, 28, 20, 13, 15, 5, 1, 18, 10,
         10, 10]
NUM_COLORS = len(sizes)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 5))

# set color theme
# https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_summary.html#colors-in-matplotlib
theme = plt.get_cmap('bwr')
ax1.set_color_cycle([theme(
    1. * i / NUM_COLORS) for i in range(NUM_COLORS)])

box = ax1.get_position()
ax1.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 1.3, box.height])

_, _, autotexts = ax1.pie(
    sizes, autopct=autopct_generator(7), startangle=90, radius=1.8 * 1000)
for autotext in autotexts:
    autotext.set_weight('bold')
ax1.axis('equal')
total = sum(sizes)
plt.legend(
    loc='upper left',
    labels=['%s, %1.1f%%' % (
        l, (float(s) / total) * 100) for l, s in zip(labels, sizes)],
    prop={'size': 12},
    bbox_to_anchor=(0.0, 1),
    bbox_transform=fig1.transFigure
)
# fig1.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)
fig1.savefig('chart.png')
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you turn on the axes of the pie chart,

```
ax.pie(..., radius=1800, frame=True)
```

you'll see that the radius is indeed applied correctly.

[image]

If you want to let the axes appear larger in the plot, you may use the [subplot parameters](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html).

```
fig.subplots_adjust(left,bottom,right,top)
```

Example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sizes = [15, 30, 45, 10, 10, 24, 13, 18, 28, 20, 13, 15, 5, 1, 18, 10,
         10, 10]
labels = ["Frogs %s" % i for i in sizes]

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 5))
fig1.subplots_adjust(0.3,0,1,1)


theme = plt.get_cmap('bwr')
ax1.set_prop_cycle("color", [theme(1. * i / len(sizes)) for i in range(len(sizes))])

_, _ = ax1.pie(sizes, startangle=90)

ax1.axis('equal')

total = sum(sizes)
plt.legend(
    loc='upper left',
    labels=['%s, %1.1f%%' % (
        l, (float(s) / total) * 100) for l, s in zip(labels, sizes)],
    prop={'size': 11},
    bbox_to_anchor=(0.0, 1),
    bbox_transform=fig1.transFigure
)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Just to give an idea of the Size of pie chart, in pylab , default radius = 1.